# I’m trying to imagine an Earth-like planet around Barnard’s star

Tags: science-based, planets, atmosphere, terraforming

What I have established about this planet is that it is the size of Earth but it is located 2.2 AU from Barnard’s star, a red dwarf. I’m trying to figure out how much greenhouse gases are needed to keep the planet in an Earth-like temperature.

Comment: Such a planet would be an iceball. Even greenhouse gasses would be frozen. It would also need to be a captured planet. An accreted planet would still have most of its hydrogen due to the lack of stellar wind to blow it away.

Comment: To get the best answers, you should limit yourself to one precise question. Here you ask about greenhouse gase-ing your planet + what the sky would look like (and how well you'd see). Pick the most important one for you, deal with the other in another question :).

Comment: Could you give more specific information about this imaginary planet? "A planet" sounds extraordinarily vague.

Comment: Hi, Joachim. I imagined the planet to be the same size as Earth, with a Mars-like composition.

Comment: Bernard's star is a M4.0V star.  According to the table in the answer by User 17707 to this question https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40746/how-would-the-characteristics-of-a-habitable-planet-change-with-stars-of-differe/40758#40758, the Earth Equivalent Distance or EED where a planet receives the same amount of radiation as Earth gets from the Sun would be 0.163 AU for a M2V star and 0.0547 AU for a M5V star.   Continued.

Comment: Continued.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnard%27s_Star#:~:text=Barnard's%20Star%20is%20a%20red,in%20the%20Milky%20Way%20galaxy.  Barnard's star has a bolometric Luminosity of 0.0035 that of the Sun.  Thus its EED should be at 0.059 AU.  2.2 AU would be 37.288 time the EED of Barnard's star, so a planet at 2.2 AU would receive 1 divided by 1,.390,394.944, or 0.00000071 as much radiation as Earth does, or about as much as Pluto does.  Continued.

Comment: Continued A world at that distance from Barnard's Star would need to get many times as much energy from another source as from its star.  If it was a giant moon orbiting a giant planet at the right orbit, it might experience enough tidal heating to be warm enough if it's atmosphere trapped all the infrared light emitted from the surface. 
Possibly someone else could calculate whether that would be possible.  The planet would probably not get enough light for photosynthesis, especially if its atmosphere was opaque to visible light.

Comment: @Robert Rapplean  Fredrik Hansing imagines the planet would be about the same size as Earth, so it shouldn't accumulate enough hydrogen to become a gas giant.  according to table 2 on page 16  at https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf  humans may be able to tolerate breathing at lot of hydrogen  - if the hydrogen-oxygen mixture isn't  in combustible proportions.   Continued

Comment: @Robert Rapplean  Continued.  Some studies indicate that high atmospheric hydrogen can extende the outer limits of the liquid water habitable zone.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0021    https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08618

Comment: @M.A.Golding, My understanding of planetary accretion is that you only get earth-like rocky planets closer to the star, where stellar wind blows the lighter elements away. Pluto isn't really a rocky planet, it's a trans-Neptunian object, basically a bigger asteroid that is too far out for gas giants to knock it out of the sky or absorb it. This is all theory, of course.